# The (View v) in Android studio is always "Cannot Resolve", and red no matter what

Tags: java, android

I've tried everything even re-syncing and reinstalling Android studio. The onClick(View v) the "v" is always red and it says Cannot resolve symbol. I've imported view.OnclickListener too and View.view, and still the same thing. I can't even compile the code, or even build the APK.
here is the code:

```
package com.example.alexm.calc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          EditText percentedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentedit);
          EditText valueedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueedit);
          Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
          TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());{
             public void onClick(View v){

             }
          }


    }
}
```

and here is the error log:

```
Error:(24, 13) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(24, 20) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(24, 32) error: ';' expected
Error:(24, 39) error: ';' expected
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Notice even when I put ';" semicolon it will say "Unnecessary ";""
it is bugging me so much. Plese help

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a semicolon in there that you don't need.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());{
```

Should look like

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    // onClick... 
});
```

Comment: OMG! IT FIXED IT :S Thank you so much!, i actually wanted to write it like that but android force it to be like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! it fixed. It was misplaced semi-colon and ")" by android studio auto place.